# Azure Function Event Grid Trigger is retrying 5 times without failure

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I have an Event Grid Trigger that processes files and pushes to a SQL database in Python using `pandas to_sql()`. The `to_sql()` call takes about 2-3 minutes. While data is being pushed to my database, the event grid trigger restarts and starts a new function invocation. This happens 5 times before it stops. I've confirmed that only one event grid message is sent and there are no errors thrown in the Python script. All settings are default and this is my host.json:

```json
  "extensions": {
    "eventHubs": {
      "maxEventBatchSize": 1,
      "clientRetryOptions": {
        "mode" : "exponential",
        "tryTimeout" : "00:10:00"
      }
    }
  },
```

How is the event grid trigger getting triggered when no messages are being sent and no errors are being thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at the doc: [Event Grid message delivery and retry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry), where is described your problem such as that the Event Grid didn't receive a response within 30 seconds.

In your case, where the subscriber needs more processing time (2-3 minutes), the event message should be pushed to the pullup resource such as a queue and then pull-up it based on the needs.

Comment: do you think just a QueueTrigger would be better for my case?

Comment: The event message should be delivered to the storage queue destination resource and then the QueueTrigger function will pull up it. Note, that the AEG delivery responsibility is ending by storing an event message into the storage queue.